# Run-Time Error 1004 when attempting to lock cell in worksheet protected with UserInterface Only := True

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

Build a new excel workbook and add the following code to an inserted `module1`.

In the worksheet enter:

- "Test FixDate" to cell A1.
- Merge and Center cells F1:H1.
- Unlock Cells F1.
- Enter formula in F1 `= Today()`

In the Formula Tab Define Name `TodaysDate` as `$F$1:$H$1`.
Rename the worksheet "Test"

In the Immediate window type `Protect` and press Enter.
Next type `FixDate` and press Enter.

A run-time error 1004 occurs on line:

```
rng.Locked = True
```

Note that the value in Range `TodaysDate` is changed to the text provided by the message box, but the cell properties of the range cannot be changed unless the worksheet is unprotected. I wish to change the color of the range `TodaysDate` to match the color of Cell A1, too. This property change also fails with run-time 1004. I have omitted the attempt from the code in building the example to be as simple as possible.

Is this an Excel bug? or have I missed some restriction about setting the range properties?

Here is the code:

```
Option Explicit

Global Const gPassword As String = "password"

Sub FixDate()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Set wks = Worksheets("Test")
    wks.Activate
    Set rng = Range("TodaysDate")
    If ActiveWorkbook.FileFormat <> xlOpenXMLTemplateMacroEnabled _
       And ActiveWorkbook.FileFormat <> xlOpenXMLTemplate _
        And ActiveWorkbook.FileFormat <> xlTemplate Then
        If Not rng.Locked Then
            '   Let user change the date; today's date is default
            rng.Value = InputBox("Enter competition date (mm/dd/yy), if not today.", Range("A1"), Format(Now(), "mm/dd/yy"))
            rng.Copy
            rng.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
            False, Transpose:=False
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            rng.Locked = True
        End If
    End If
    Application.Goto Reference:=rng, Scroll:=False
    Set rng = Nothing
    Set wks = Nothing
End Sub

Public Sub ProtectWorkbook(Optional UnProtect As Boolean = False)
    '
    '   Workbook is protected (or optionally unprotected) in such a way as to allow code to change the data
    '   without unprotecting worksheets but human interface needs password.
    '
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim wksActive As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer
    Set wksActive = ActiveSheet
    For Each wks In Worksheets
        With wks
            If .Name = "Roster" Then
               On Error Resume Next
               .Visible = xlSheetHidden
            End If
            wks.UnProtect Password:=gPassword
            If UnProtect = False Then wks.Protect Password:=gPassword, UserInterfaceOnly:=True
        End With
    Next wks
    Set wks = Nothing
    wksActive.Activate
    Set wksActive = Nothing
End Sub

Public Sub Protect()
    ProtectWorkbook UnProtect:=False
End Sub

Public Sub UnProtect()
    ProtectWorkbook UnProtect:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: No-repro on Excel 2016. No-repro on Excel 2003.

Comment: The error only occurs if, contrary to your detailed instructions, you assign the `TodaysDate` name to the range `$F$1`, as opposed to `$F$1:$H$1`. Yes, this is what happens by default in newer Excels when you select the merged cell: the name manager will pick up the address of the first cell. You need to manually correct it before saving. With `TodaysDate` being `$F$1:$H$1`, the error does not occur.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the offending code (rng.locked = true) and replace with 
  Selection.Locked = True
  Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = wks.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 1)).Interior.ColorIndex

This code runs OK without unprotecting the sheet.
It still does not explain why the Range object rng fails. I would be interested in any comment about that.

Thanks

Comment: You [should not use `Selection`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/11683). It works for you because `Selection` of a merged cell returns a range that covers the entire merged cell (F1:H1), whereas your [incorrectly assigned name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51153002/run-time-error-1004-when-attempting-to-lock-cell-in-worksheet-protected-with-use#comment89290125_51153002) only covers F1.